# What is the meaning/usage of に in the following sentence?

Tags: usage, particles, particle-に

> ある事柄について感じた事(が、発表できる程度**に**まとまったもの)。

So, I understand the first sentence, but I'm a little confused about the second one.

My translation is: to have a feeling about a certain matter to the extent of being able to declare about it.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't this an excerpt of a dictionary definition, like what [this blog cites](http://blog.livedoor.jp/bokuryu/archives/10319966.html)?

> 「感想」…ある事柄について感じた事（が、発表出来る程度にまとまったもの）。

In this case, it means:

> what one thinks/feels about a certain matter (which has taken shape enough to be expressed/presented/published)

As you have correctly translated, 程度 means "(to) the extent/degree", or you could take Vできる程度 altogether as "enough to V". Anyway, both ～程度 and ～程度に stands for the adverbial phrase "to the degree", but the form with に is preferred when describing the state how the result is, while without に the manner how the action is done.

> 30cm程度切る *cut (off) 30cm*
>   30cm程度に切る *cut into 30cm pieces* or *trim into 30cm long*

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer: the に in 発表できる程度にまとまったもの  allows the adverb of degree 程度(extent) to modify まとまった.

発表できる程度 translates to "the extent it can be presented".

まとまる in this context translates to "to come together; to cohere".

In order to say that ある事柄について感じた事 has まとまった to 発表できる程度, we use に.

So:

> ある事柄について感じた事(が、発表できる程度にまとまったもの)。

becomes, in English:

> (The substance of) what you felt about a certain matter (that has become coherent enough to be able to be presented (outwardly)).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that both parts of your sentence describe the `もの` mentioned at the very end of the sentence.

> ある事柄について感じた事がまとまったもの

A thing that collects the things felt about a certain matter.

> 発表できる程度にまとまったもの

A thing that collects (something) to the degree of being able to present (it).